# What does "en" refer to in the phrase "elle en a fait des heureux"?

Tags: sens, pronoms

> Un compte pro en ligne est désormais la démarche tendance pour faciliter la gestion des avoirs de son entreprise. Que ce soit pour une activité récente ou pour une autre vieille de plusieurs années, ce genre de prestation est l’idéale pour les professionnels. Simple et rapide, **elle en a fait des heureux** depuis quelques années maintenant.

I wonder if the last sentence should be interpreted as:

> Ce genre de prestation {elle} a fait des heureux **du fait d’être simple et rapide**.

On another note: Does "X (en) fait des heureux" tend to be accompanied by the pronoun "en" like this?

Answer (score 3):

I would say "en" simply refers to "des heureux" and the object is repeated for emphasis. I would add a comma for better comprehension: "Elle en a fait, des heureux", where "des heureux" comes as a precision. It would be equivalent to drop the "en": "Elle a fait des heureux", which is a colloquial expression.

Another possible reading is that "en" refers to "les professionnels": it made professionals happy. Then the expression would be "faire de quelqu'un un heureux" but it seems less colloquial to me.

Comment: The same construction as "Tu en as, de la chance !", I take it? The omission of the comma had me puzzled, I guess.

Comment: @Alone-zee yes that's it!

Answer (score 2):

***En*** refers to *heureux*, i.e. the customers, the ***professionnels***.

> Elle en a fait des heureux

=

> Elle a rendu heureux beaucoup de professionnels

Comment: Strongly agreed. "She made happy people of them (=the professionals)", where "of them" translates "en".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Quentin rightly points the sentence should have included a comma. The idiom is *elle en a fait, des heureux !* -> "Lucky people, it made a lot of them".

Comment: Well, in that case, I've misread both the passage and your answer v_v

Comment: @LukeSawczak I mean *en* refers to *des heureux* and *des heureux* applies to *des professionnels*.

Comment: Indeed, which is not how my reading works; the unpronominal version of mine would go *Elle a fait des heureux des professionnels.*

Comment: @LukeSawczak I get where you're coming from on this one. You have something like this in mind, I gather. "*J'ai la chance de faire **de** ma passion mon travail.*" --- "*Le tennis est la passion de ma vie, et j'ai la chance d'**en** faire mon travail.*"

Comment: @Alone-zee Exactly, and I think the grammar allows for that, but if the other reading comes more naturally to native speakers I can't contest that. Also, it's true that (in this sentence, anyway) it comes to the same thing.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, the grammar definitively allows this understanding but not the semantics. Unlike *malheureux*, *heureux* is an adjective not substantivized enough to allow *faire de quelqu'un **un heureux***. That would have worked with *depuis quelques années maintenant, elle en a fait des clients satisfaits.*